# Magento: Customer Registration breaks after failed validation

Tags: forms, validation, magento

On my registration page for Magento I am seeing a very unusual error. When a customer submits the form, it goes through with no issues.

If they submit the form and the validation fails it will show them the related validation issues. If they solve all of their validation issues, they cannot submit the form again.

If they solve only some of their validation issues, it will show the new issues that break it.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Any tips on solving it? We are completely stumped.

Using Magento 1.5 with a custom template

Comment: Are you able to update your post with specific details of how it breaks? Are you seeing any exceptions, error messages, http error pages etc? If nothing is displaying visibly on the page, could you try debugging the validation javascript (as kungphu suggested) to see if there are any js problems - if the console doesn't work i recommend trying Firebug's javascript step debugger - it can be very useful for debugging the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Please include this javascript file - effects.js in the scriptaculous folder of prototype library. Magento use this js to fade in and fade out of error messages. When validate first time magento prototype library validate the fields and show error messages again submitting magento tries to fade out the error message. If above js file is not included the operation will break up.
Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case the file was present but was not included in the header once I include the file it is working like a Charm.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is extraordinarily difficult to work with... have you watched the javascript console to see if there's an issue there?  If the form is unpredictably doing something script-illegal under those circumstances and the template is submitting only with JS, perhaps that's why it won't submit.